# AWS serverless: Failed to build the Java bridge when invoking locally a lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-serverless

As part of my AWS training, I'm trying to locally deploy a simple lambda function in Java that converts a string from lower to upper case.

```
package org.example;
    public class SimpleHandler implements RequestHandler<String, String> {
    @Override
        public String handleRequest(String s, Context context) {
            return s.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
```

Below is the serverless.yaml file:

```
service: myPlayGround

provider:
  name: aws
  region: eu-west-1
  runtime: java17

package:
  artifact: target/serverless_playGround-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

functions:
  myTestFunction:
    handler: org.example.SimpleHandler::handleRequest
```

When I run the command: sls invoke local -f myTestFunction

I'm getting the following error: "Failed to build the Java bridge. exit code=1 signal=null"

Any insight would be helpful as I couldn't find any solution to fix the issue.

Comment: How do you compile your code?

Comment: @stdunbar, I compile the code with command: mvn clean package. This creates a snapshot jar file.

Comment: And your `pom.xml` includes, for example, the shade plugin?

Comment: yes, pom.xml include the shade dependency:  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: I'm able to upload and test the same function in AWS, but it doesn't work when I invoke it locally through serverless.yml